# DynamoDB GSI: update indexed attribute, keep previous index entry

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table:

```
public class Status {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String requestId;

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = TASK_ID_INDEX)
    private String taskId;
}
```

*(some fields omitted for simplicity)*

When I add an entry for `requestId: A, taskId: 1`, I can see a corresponding entry in the global secondary index. When I update the entry to `requestId: A, taskId: 2`, I still see one entry in the GSI, the one for `taskId: 2`.

Is there a way to keep both entries in the index, one for `taskId: 1`, and another for `taskId: 2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a GSI as a materialized view on top of the base DynamoDB table and the GSI contains only those records that are present in the base table.

So, if you update the record in the base table, the update eventually propagates to the GSI and you can only have one record at any point of time, either with the old state (before update propagates) or with the new state (after the update propagates, but not both.

You seem to need to keep track of history of changes and that should be a separate table.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's the approach I'm going for. Indexing on a collection could have done the trick, but that's unsupported.

Comment: If you are trying to version objects, the DynamoDB SDK can do this for you with optimistic locking. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html